# Download CSV file in jquery mobile framewrok with zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, jquery-mobile

I am doing project with jquery mobile framework using zend framework.I have the page to download report in csv format. I can downloaded it from desktop version. But the same page in mobile version runs in ajax due to jquery mobile result `undefined` with `blank page`.

for example, i call this  http://www.test.com/report/downloadtransaction when i click download button. This calls downloadtransactionAction in reportcontroller ,then finally gives  csv file.
Call is happening in mobile version but not able to see download file window.

Below is the code

```
 public function downloadtransactionAction(){
                    $preview_result = getmySessionData('preview_result')->preview_key;
                    //print_obj($preview_result);        
                    $myFile = "TRANSACTION_" . time() . ".csv";
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$myFile\"");
                    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-16LE");
                    $out = fopen("php://output", 'w');
                    //$csvData = array('Warehouse Id', 'Name','Item No','Minimun Stock','Current Stock');
                    $csvData = array('No','DATE','USER', 'TRADE TYPE','AMOUNT');
                    $o = fputcsv($out, $csvData, ',', '"');
                    $count = 1;;
                    foreach($preview_result as $key => $value)
                    {

                        $csvData = array();
                        $csvData = array($count,date('Y/m/d',strtotime($value['date'])),$value['current_admin_name'],($value['trade_type'])?'WithDraw' : 'Deposit',$value['amount']);
                        $o = fputcsv($out, $csvData, ',', '"');
                        $count++;
                    }
                    fclose($fh);
                    // DOWNLOAD CSV
                    echo $out;
                    die;
    }
```

I need to download csv in mobile version as like in desktop version
What i done wrong on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code to disable the ajax in jquery mobile framework,

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // do not handle links via ajax by default
            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () { $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; });
        </script>
```

This will disable the ajax in page and make redirecting to clicked page.